# Composite in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

In a panel, I added 3 composite

```
public class frame {

//Initialization
....
....
public Service service = new Service();

public frame () {
    initWidget(getFramePanel());
}

private HorizontalPanel getFramePanel() { 
    if (hp== null) {
        hp= new HorizontalPanel();
        hp.setSize("1442px", "750px");
        hp.add(getTree());// **are composites**
        hp.add(getTable()); // **are composite**

    }
    return hp;
}
```

What I understand is that both these `tree` and `table` are added to `hp` in the same class , so I can use variable or object initialized in this class, in both the composites

**ex :** `service` object is in class `frame`, so i want to know whethr i can use `service` in both the composite .

in tree and table composite. If yes then How?

**this code may not be correct because I didn't copy paste the code .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Observer pattern, create an interface that has a method to call the service, eg. "callService" and create an object **"MyInterfaceImpl"** that **implements this interface in class "frame"**.  This object will implement the interface such that it will get and use both children (getTree() and getTable()) composite's values.

Pass this object **MyInterfaceImpl** to both composites, **either through a constructor or a method,** then you can always invoke this object **MyInterfaceImpl**'s method from either composites' UI objects' eventHandler.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the service in any callbacks, event handlers, etc. you set on the tree and table.  But I believe you have to make it final.